# Android multiple buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am working on an Android app that has multiple buttons on the same activity.

Now I already made a background picture and just put the buttons on top of the background (hence invisible buttons).

I want to make all three buttons work e.g. back button, scan button, profile button etc work. But I am encountering a problem.

This what I have and need to fix.

```
  <Button
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text = "scan"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/scan"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_ centerHorizontal="true" />

  <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="back"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/scan1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

  <Button
        style="?android:attribute/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="profile"
        android:background="@drawable/scan2"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />
```

it gives me errors on

> android:background="@drawable/scan1"(so does the other button) and
>   android:layout_alignParentStart="false"

Comment: What's the parent layout for these buttons?

Comment: ^this and are those warnings or errors?

Comment: relative Layout and they are errors.

If you have any other solution like an examples of adding buttons over the background then making them invisible, i am willing to listen to that as well.

Comment: Please mention the exact errors. Your question is missing key details. My guess is that your resource `scan1` is not a drawable.